# Random flling the array - perl

Tags: arrays, perl, random

I need to know how can I fill the array in perl randomly. For example: I want declare an array containing 10 elements smaller than 60. Can someone explain me how can I do it or send me any guide? I would be so grateful.

Comment: Use a loop and the push command to put a new random number into the array with each loop iteration.

Comment: See `shuffle()` in `perldoc List::Util` http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#@values-=-shuffle-@values `List::Util` is a standard module that is installed with Perl. For a list of all the standard modules, see `perldoc perlmodlib` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html

Comment: @shawnhcorey: `shuffle` returns a list in random order, it doesn't build random values.

Comment: @Toto, You'd use `shuffle` if you wanted all ten elements to be different. See my answer.

Comment: @Toto: See the first link in my above comment. It has an example of how to populate randomly with the numbers 0 .. 51.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant "ten non-negative integers less than 60".

With possibility of repeats:

```
my @rands = map { int(rand(60)) } 1..10;
```

For example,

```
$ perl -E'say join ",", map { int(rand(60)) } 1..10;'
0,28,6,49,26,19,56,32,56,16       <-- 56 is repeated

$ perl -E'say join ",", map { int(rand(60)) } 1..10;'
15,57,50,16,51,58,46,7,17,53

$ perl -E'say join ",", map { int(rand(60)) } 1..10;'
13,57,26,47,30,14,47,55,39,39     <-- 47 and 39 are repeated
```

Without possibility of repeats:

```
use List::Util qw( shuffle );

my @rands = (shuffle 0..59)[0..9];
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -E'say join ",", (shuffle 0..59)[0..9];'
13,50,8,21,11,24,28,51,55,38

$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -E'say join ",", (shuffle 0..59)[0..9];'
1,0,58,46,47,49,52,33,5,13

$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -E'say join ",", (shuffle 0..59)[0..9];'
19,43,45,49,23,53,2,38,59,35
```

Comment: I haven't considered use shuffle like this. +1

Comment: So when I want fill an array contain 'n' elements, can I use: "@rand = map {int (rand(60)) } n;"? Or create a loop 'for' and enter counts in this way?: "my $tab[$i] = map {int (rand(60)) };". I used second option before the moment and my compiler showed errors. What's wrong?

Comment: The first will only assign one element, and I'd be hard pressed to find something that isn't wrong with the second snippet.

Comment: So if nothing is wrong what about the compiler errors? Furthermore it seems my compiler isn't read prefix "my" (is not coloured)

Comment: I didn't say nothing was wrong; I said it was completely wrong. It's like someone made up a sentence by picking random words from a dictionary.

Comment: Indeed, I misinterpreted. Finally I used this way: "my @tab = { int (rand(60)) 1..$n+1". Work irreproachable.

Comment: That doesn't compile, and that returns n+1 results.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
my @r = map int(rand(60)), 0..9;
say Dumper\@r;
```

Comment: I was just typing that out with `1..10` :)

Comment: @simbabque: I've saved one char. ;-)

Comment: You could save more by using [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) and even get free colos! `p @r` =)

Answer (score -1):

You could take advantage of perl's random sorting of hash keys. This will fill an array of 10 elements randomly each time you run it:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @nums = (1 .. 60);

my %data;

$data{$_}++ foreach @nums;

my $count = 0;
my @random;
foreach (keys %data){
    $count++;
    push @random, $_ if $count <= 10;
}
```

Comment: That is one arcane solution

Comment: That's not really random, it gives the same result on each run.

Comment: @Toto, Not in newer versions of Perl, and not always in old versions of Perl, but I agree that's not the way to go. For starters, I think it's not completely random.

Comment: @simbabque - I would say it's the least arcane answer here. It's also easier to understand for someone new to perl than `map` etc

Comment: I don't agree with that, but I think that that discussion is best had over a beer or two.  ;)

Comment: @simbabque Are you hitting on me?

Comment: It's moot talking about readability when you don't even have a working solution. Feel free to replace the `map` with a more complicated `for`+`push`, but don't replace `rand` with hash key orderings. What you posted is **awful**.

Comment: @ikegami can join us for the beers =)

Comment: @simbabque sure, but `drinks` are on **him**